Talend TOS synchronization problem tflowtoiterate
I have a flow which retrieves countries and cities in an excel file and which will execute a query with the city  on a database and which will save the result in a file bearing the name of the country, the problem that the first line of each country is found at the end of the previous file (of the previous country) I don't know why



I have this in my file United-Kingdom.xlsx

and i have this in my file France.xlsx

anyone can help me please ?

is the content of tLogRow_1 OK or KO ?

@Corentin yes it's ok but i don't know why  the first row for france it's write in United-kingdom.xlxs and the first row on United-kingdom is writ in null.xlsx

I don't know if it's related, but in tFileOutputExcel_1, you've set "row3.country" as part of your filename : I think it should be row1.country here (name of the flow entering your tFlowToIterate_1 component). Let me know if it works better

@Corentin thank's it's work like that, !  Why does it not work correctly with  "row3.country" ?

Actually , Talend is a bit too permissive : you should have put ((String)globalMap.get("row1.country")) in your tFileOutputExcel : this is the name of the globalvariable that tFlowToIterate has created automatically when connected to tFileInputExcel through row1, and the one you want to use. It's better to use the global variable rather than the name of the input flow . row3.country refers to the input arriving in tFileOutputExcel, most of the components are not able to access this data directly.
